# Data Import Wizard overwriting Account Names

Tags: data, import

I have about 1600 contacts that I need to bulk import into Salesforce. Some of the contacts already exist in Salesforce and are assigned to Accounts. For the existing ones I just need to check a checkbox and leave everything else in tact.
The file with contacts includes Names, and email addresses, checkbox state, but does not include Account names. Therefore I manually created a column with a common XY Account, hoping that new contacts will be assigned XY account and the existing will stay as they are because I left "Update existing Account information" checkbox unchecked.
I ran a test on a few contacts and it doesn't work this way. All contacts were assigned XY account without exception.
How do I add new and update existing contacts without messing up existing account assignments?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can login to Dataloader.io, connect to your org and then Export all your Contacts data first. (Or, you can just go to Setup->data export-> (and export your data, a zip file will be ready to be downloaded once, the export is ready) (I **strongly** suggest the use of Dataloader.io)
2. Then you can open the CSV and edit the CSV, for all the Contact that you want to check the checkbox, find the column with the checkbox field Api name, and set the value to true.
3. Insert the new Contact details, in the CSV and for their AccountId, put the XY's AccountId in the cell for each new contact.
4. Using [Dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io/), or [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or Salesforce Data Import Wizard (which I believe you are using now) 
   -> Workbench: Data->Upsert->From file->Choose the CSV file that you have edited.
   ->Dataloder.io: Export->Upsert->(do the necessary mappings and proceed).
   ->Data Import Wizard: Accounts and Contacts -> Add new and update existing records->Match Contact by Id, Match Account by Id -> Choose the CSV that you edited -> Do the necessary mappings and proceed.

In general, Upsert means, it will insert new records and update existing records on one go. Which is what you want in your case, to update the existing contacts and create new contacts.

Here I am assuming, you have created an Account called XY, in your ORG and it has a ID, which you can use to populate in the AccountId column, for your new contacts.

If you need further assistance, or clarification, do let me know in the comment section, I am more than happy to help you further! Hope it helps! :)